# Connection from connector's pin to another connector's pin

Tags: excel, vba, visio, connector, pins

Is there any way to select "pin" in this method?:

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).AutoConnect
```

I want to connect two shapes and then I want to connect third one onto created connection, but not at beginning, I need to connect it onto fourth pin. This is what I have:
[image]
This is what I want to have:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get center of shape we have to use this lines.

```
Set object = AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(objectId)
connectingXfrom = object .CellsU("PinX").Result("in")
connectingYfrom = object .CellsU("PinY").Result("in")
```

The center of shape **object** is at point C[connectingXfrom, connectingYfrom]

Next two lines move first point of connector to point P[connectingXfrom, connectingYfrom]

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(connectorShapeId).CellsSRC(1, 4, 0).FormulaU = connectingXfrom
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(connectorShapeId).CellsSRC(1, 4, 1).FormulaU = connectingYfrom
```

If we want to start connecting from **connection 1** but close to **object 2**, we need to do:

```
connectingXfrom = connectingXfrom - someDistanceValue
```

- someDistanceValue can be for example 1.5
- objectId is Id of Object 2 shape
- connectorShapeId is Id of connection 2 shape.